# Integrating two solutions in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, assemblies

There's one solution which is an upgraded version from VB to .Net. It's a huge project with myriad of library references to third party softwares. The other is built purely on .Net reflection(parallel framework code for concurrency and key certs for scheduled jobs). As a matter of fact there are properties for each of the solutions with dedicated assembly files, settings and resources.

The requirement is to integrate 2nd solution to first one. I managed to transfer stand alone files, without much pain into the main project. But I am not sure what my options are. How to include both assembly files into one project? How to combine the two project properties?

Comment: **There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.**

Comment: @JeremyThompson What sort of details do you require? There's no particular coding bug per se (at least for now) but I would appreciate an approach that I could follow to get two solutions combined into one. I checked [through this post though adding as a reference is still a bit over my head.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/49550/Combine-two-different-project-in-C)

Comment: Need more details than you've provided... you don't even mention the application type (Winform, ASP.Net, WPF, etc), or the solution architecture (eg 3 tier, MVC, MVVM) or what you've tried that didn't work. Thats why its too broad and a little bit like a shopping question in that you want a bunch of options to solve the integration when the problem domain is not known to us. I'll provide my 2 cents *a) How to include both assembly files into one project?* **Simply import the 2nd Solutions' Projects into the 1st Solution** *b) How to combine the two project properties?* **Refactor them in.**

Comment: Each project should be self-contained within a single directory (with possible sub-directories). You can create a new .sln with existing projects by using "Add Existing..." when adding your projects to the .sln, When doing this, you can specify either the projects in their original location, or you can actually copy the project directories to a new location with the new .sln file. If the latter, then of course you have effectively branched the projects; changes in one directory won't be reflected in the other and vice a versa.

Comment: Beyond that, your question really is too broad. You should make an attempt to accomplish your goal, and then if you have a problem, post a question asking for help with that _specific problem_. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to keep the scope of your question limited enough to remain on-topic here.

Comment: @JeremyThompson please add your comment as an answer. I tried that out. Now I do not have to worry about any assemblies being merged in. All projects are working collectively together yet in their own `shell`. I will proceed to consume the latter functionalisties in the main solution.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am quite ashamed of my questioning style of this post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide my 2 cents

*a) How to include both assembly files into one project?*

**Simply import the 2nd Solutions' Projects into the 1st Solution**

*b) How to combine the two project properties?*

**You will need to Refactor them in.**